# Change UIImageView image half way of a flip animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, cgaffinetransform

How can I change the image of a UIImageView on half way of a Flip animation.
My code does seem to flip the UIImageView and successfully change the image but it is changing in an instant. What I want to achieve is to only change the image once the 180 flip reaches the 90 degree flip. Here is my code:

Create UIImageView on view:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fb1.jpg"];
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    vw = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 80, 80)];
    vw.layer.cornerRadius = vw.frame.size.width / 2;
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 80, 80);
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width / 2;
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    imageView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
    [self.view addSubview: imageView];
    //[self.view addSubview:vw];
    [imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(taptap:)];
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

Animate UIImageView on Tap:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^(void) {
                         imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1);
                         [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                                          animations:^(void) {
                                              imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fb2.jpg"];
                                          } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                                          }];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     }];
```

Also, I am doing this animation on a tap gesture on the specific UIImageView.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194752/how-can-i-flip-a-uiimageview

Comment: The answer I tried to follow on that link makes my rounded UIImageView square when the flipping starts.

Answer (score 22):

You can use `UIView` class method `+ (void)transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:` for this animation easily.

Use code like this for your animation:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:imageView
                  duration:0.4
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                animations:^{
                    //  Set the new image
                    //  Since its done in animation block, the change will be animated
                    imageView.image = newImage;
                } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    //  Do whatever when the animation is finished
                }];
```

You can set direction of flip by replacing `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight` with any of the following options:

```
UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop
UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom
```

Comment: Thanks for this but the animation I need is an animation like a flipping coin where I only want the image to be change once the coin is half way to being turned.

Comment: I dont get what exaclty you are trying to accomplish. You want 180° flip animation (from one side of paper to the other) or full 360° flip rotation  animation? My code makes the 180° flip animation: Makes the 90° (half-flip) so the image has visually width=0, changes the image and returns the width back to original one)

Comment: That is what I am trying to achieve. After the half-flip I want the image to be immediately changed.

Comment: Okay, your code seems to be doing what I want to do. But I forgot to mention one important detail and that is the UIImageView I am flipping is rounded. It has a cornerRadius half of its height so it looks like a circle. When flipping it is turning into a square then a circle again. Any suggestion?

Comment: There is no reason for this. Just tried it myself with the corner radius set and the radius is properly kept during the flip animation. Maybe you have problem somewhere else

Comment: I've added my code for creating the UIImageView, I cannot detect which seems to be causing the problem. Can you post your code with corner radius?

Comment: Your `imageView` code is fine and works for me. Hovewer I don't know what the `vw` view is indented for. And isn't the gesture recognizer touch causing some highlights for example? I recommend go step by step by commenting out the functionality until you find the problem. Try to remove the `vw`, gesture recognizer etc

Comment: Any progress on this? I have exactly the same example. A circle image, flipping to turn on another image. But when it flips, it turns square, then a circle again. I found out that this happens when I add the second image, but cant fix it.

Answer (score 3):

For Swift

```
UIView.transition(with: imageView,
                  duration: 0.4,
                  options: UIView.AnimationOptions.transitionFlipFromLeft,
                  animations: {
                      imageView.image = newImage
        }, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a two steps animation, if you don't like this you can lookup the documentation for concatenating options.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^(void) {
                     //do your half rotation here
                     imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0, 1);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     if(finished){
                         imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fb2.jpg"];
                         [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                                          animations:^(void) {
                                              //do your second half rotation here
                                              imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1);
                                          } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                                          }];
                     }
                 }];
```